# How can i dynamically render some code inside a ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

I'm generating View components dynamically in my render() function.

The list can be longer than the size of my screen. how can i surround my return statement inside of a ScrollView ?

```js
   render() {

        if (this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Chargement</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                </View>
            );
        }

        return Object.entries(this.state.results).map(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(key, value)
            return (
                <View key={key} style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>{key}</Text>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(value.reps)}</Text>
                    <Text>{JSON.stringify(value.weight)}</Text>
                    <Button title="delete">Delete</Button>
                </View>
            )
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
render(){
  return(
  <ScrollView>
  {
    Object.entries(this.state.results).map(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(key, value)
      return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.container}>
              <Text>{key}</Text>
              <Text>{JSON.stringify(value.reps)}</Text>
              <Text>{JSON.stringify(value.weight)}</Text>
              <Button title="delete">Delete</Button>
          </View>
      )
  })
  }
  </ScrollView>
 )
```

}